# apt upgrade: start a new shell to examine the situation. Where?

Tags: apt, configuration, upgrade

When I do a dist upgrade, I often get prompts about config files like this:

```
Configuration file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** bash.bashrc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

When I choose `Z`, where should I be looking? There are no `.dpkg-old` or `.dpkg-new` files in /etc/php5/apache2/, nor in the directory where I started apt.

Answer (score 3):

> When I choose Z, where should I be looking?

I think the idea here is to give you a chance to do some additional investigation of the current situation (beyond what `D` would do), and not necessarily so you can look at the new version from the package (since `D` + `Z` will amount to that).

> There are no .dpkg-old or .dpkg-new files

It won't do that until you've actually made a choice.